# How to connect to elasticache in my case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to connect to aws elasticache from my app.

I know the endpoint and the port but for some reason I can't connect to it.

I used this npm package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-memcached-client

code:

```
const Memcached = require('node-memcached-client');
const client = new Memcached({
  host: 'mycache.aa11c.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com', //fake aws cache endpoint
  port: 11211
});
console.log(client); // I can see it outputs stuff

client.connect()
    .then(c => {
        console.log('connected');
        console.log(c);

    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('error connecting');
        console.log(err);
    });
```

For some reason when I run the codes, all I see is

```
[Memcached] INFO: Nothing any connection to mycache.aa11c.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com:11211, created sid:1
```

no errors or `connected` message in the `console.log`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to connect from local machine or ec2 instance?

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni i am trying it from local machine.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to go over the below document from AWS to access Elasticache resources from outside of AWS:

[Access AWS Elasticache from outside](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Access.Outside.html)

I would recommend setting up a local memcached instance for development and debugging, and connect to Elasticache from an EC2 instance in test and production environments.

The ROI for trying to setup NAT and mapping the IP addresses is not justifiable for dev/test unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Above link is broken. Try: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html#access-from-outside-aws

Answer (score 0):

I ended using port forwarding to bypass the local instance can't connect to elasticache issue.

by using

```
ssh -L 11211:{your elasticache endpoint}:11211 {your ec2 instance ip}
```